# Falha na injeção de dependência

Tags: java, jsf, spring, injeção-de-dependência

Estou tendo um problema em um teste com JSF, basicamente eu tenho a entidade, o serviço e a view, não achei algo que me ajudasse a resolver.

Na view, quero chamar meu serviço pelo ManagedProperty assim:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Getter
@Setter
public class EpiView implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{epiService}")
    private EpiService epiService;

    private Epi epi;

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicia() {
        epi = epiService.epiById();
    }

}
```

e meu serviço:

```
@Service
public class EpiService {

    public Epi epiById() {
        Epi epi = new Epi();
        epi.setId(new EpiPK());
        epi.getId().setCenCust("13.02");
        epi.getId().setProduto("Bomba");
        epi.setQuantidadeDias(15);
        epi.setQuantidadeRetirada(1000);
        epi.setCategoria("Veneno");
        epi.setQntTroca(200);

        return epi;
    }

}
```

Não estou usando banco é apenas um teste, porem quando a página sobe eu tenho uma `NullPointerException`, o serviço não está sendo instanciado, se eu criar a instancia na mão `epiService = new EpiService();` ele funciona e é exibido na página normalmente, acredito que seja um problema na injeção de dependência, eu tentei também usar o `@Autowired`, porém o serviço vem `null` do mesmo jeito.

O projeto é no Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) Estou usando Maven com as seguintes dependências.

> jsf-api-2.2.12.jar jsf-impl-2.2.12.jar javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
>   spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
>   spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
>   commons-logging-1.2.jar lombok-1.18.8.jar cdi-api-1.2.jar
>   javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar

Comment: Qual sua configuração de `el-resolver`?

Comment: E se voce anotar o Servico EpiService com: "@ManagedBean(name="epiService")?. Para utilizar o managedProperty acredito que tenha que anotar mesmo.

Comment: Qualquer coisa, da uma olhada nesse guia, para ver suas dependencias tambem. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devido a integração com o Spring, você precisa fazer algumas alterações no seu código:

- Utilizar `@Component` ao invés de `@ManagedBean`
- Utilizar `@Scope("prototype")` ao invés de `@ViewScoped`
- Você pode utilizar `@Autowired` ao invés de `@ManagedProperty`

Como as anotações do JSF não são interpretadas pelo Spring, suas propriedades não serão injetadas (já que nunca foram reconhecidas pelo Spring)

Ou (mais simples):

- Deixar seu `@ManagedBean` como ele está hoje, porém realizar a seguinte alteração:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class EpiView extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {

        @Autowired
        private EpiService epiService;

        ...
    }
```

A classe [SpringBeanAutowiringSupport](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html) irá fazer com que seu bean seja reconhecido no contexto do Spring, realizando as injeções adequadamente.

---

Como complemento vou deixar alguns links para [esta thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed) do StackOverflow em inglês onde existe um detalhamento muito maior que minha resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver o problema incluindo 2 classe em meu projeto.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {

}
```

e

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(Config.class);
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    }

}
```